# Click to URL irregular highcharts graph

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have an irregular time xAxis highchart for my data.  I am trying to make it so that when a point is clicked on, I can open a new URL in another window.  I was able to get this working for a basic graph (without irregular xAxis intervals), but when I change the format of my data, I am unable to get an actual URL.

Below is my code with dummy data

```
$(function () { 
    $('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'spline', 
        zoomType: 'x'
    },
    title: {
        text: ' frequency'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Irregular time data in Highcharts JS'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        dateTimeLabelFormats: { // don't display the dummy year
            month: '%b %y, %Y',
            year: '%Y'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Date Published'
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Price ($USD)'
        },
        min: 0
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    tooltip: {
       // headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br>',
       // pointFormat: '{point.x:%b %e, %Y}: {point.y:.2f} m'
       enabled: false
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Car Price',
        color: '#CC0000',
        URLs: ['www.google.com',
'www.google.com',
'www.google.com',
'www.google.com',
'www.google.com',
'www.google.com',
'www.google.com',
'www.google.com',
'www.google.com',
'www.google.com',
'www.google.com',
'www.google.com',
'www.google.com',
'www.google.com',
],
        // Define the data points. All series have a dummy year
        // of 1970/71 in order to be compared on the same x axis. Note
        // that in JavaScript, months start at 0 for January, 1 for February etc.
        data: [
            [Date.UTC(2012, 10, 9), 37000],
[Date.UTC(2012, 11, 1), 39000],
[Date.UTC(2012, 11, 1), 10500],
[Date.UTC(2012, 11, 13), 20000],
[Date.UTC(2012, 11, 18), 33000],
[Date.UTC(2013, 5, 22), 24995],
[Date.UTC(2013, 5, 31), 15000],
[Date.UTC(2013, 6, 13), 19000],
[Date.UTC(2013, 8, 20), 4000],
[Date.UTC(2013, 9, 1), 17900],
[Date.UTC(2013, 9, 30), 2500],
[Date.UTC(2013, 11, 18), 25000], 
[Date.UTC(2014, 4, 14), 15900],
[Date.UTC(2014, 5, 16), 6900],
        ],
        point: {
            events: {
                click: function() {
                    x = this;
                    var someURL = this.series.userOptions.URLs[this.x];
                //  if (someURL)
                        window.open('http://'+someURL);
                }
            }
        }
    }]
});
});
```

Fiddle with dummy data above.
http://jsfiddle.net/5kyzkps5/1/

Can you recommend the best way to associate a URL with each point?  If the URL information can't be integrated with the data table, can you help get a correct xAxis id number? If that works I should be able to at least build an array that I could just call a URL from in the click function.  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your current code and do a `indexOf` to find the correct index for your point.

Your code:

```
var someURL = this.series.userOptions.URLs[this.x];
```

To do a index-lookup, change it to this:

```
var someURL = this.series.userOptions.URLs[this.series.data.indexOf(this)];
```

See [this JSFiddle demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/5kyzkps5/2/).

Answer (score 3):

Better is keeping url in the point object like:

```
 data:  [{x:Date.UTC(2012, 10, 9), y:37000,url:'http://www.google.com'},
            [Date.UTC(2012, 11, 1), 39000]]
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/5kyzkps5/3/

Click on the first point, url will be working.

Comment: Thanks for the syntax of this.  I may end up using this solution better organize my data.

Comment: Sebastian, I was using your structure to see if I can use information from the data in the tooltip but that doesn't seem to work correctly for me. I'm getting undefined values. Is there a way to do this as well? http://jsfiddle.net/5kyzkps5/4/